# Naming convention for the classes holding REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, naming, coding-standards

Our new team suffixes class names with API to indicate that they encapsulate RESTful methods. Eg: "PaymentTemplateAPI", "FeeTemplateAPI" classes. I find it odd since API is a general term that refers to any API/method created using any architecture style (REST, RPC, etc). I would suggest adding suffix "RestAPI" to convey that the class holds REST methods, or don’t add it at all. My vote would be for the later one only. It would be nice to understand if suffixing RESTful class names with "API" is a standard practice used everywhere. Please share your thoughts.

Though this question may still be opinion oriented, I would like to gather the perspectives of others to convince myself.

**Update**
One of the reasons behind the convention is to distinguish between the entities and API interfaces. For eg, we have a PaymentTemplate  model/entity data class for the resource and also have REST API's defined for the resource in an interface (PaymentTemplateAPI). I think the interface can be renamed to something more meaningful PaymentTemplateAccessor/PaymentTemplateReader/PaymentTemplateWriter/PaymentTemplateDAO etc. I don't think this should be the reason.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? Isn't this the same as having a mentor in person?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the question. There are a few misguided community members here who think all naming questions are too opinionated, and also think since they have the right of downvoting without commenting, it is also a good idea to never comment their voting.

Comment: Thanks to people like you, people are learning a lot.

Comment: You can use any convention you like, so long as it's used *consistently.*  And you don't need anyone else's permission to do it (except, perhaps, for your coworkers).

Comment: Even if there's not a general convention, there may be a strong convention within a specific language or framework, like the class name suffix *Controller* in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a programming language which supports namespaces (and most popular OO languages do), it does not make any sense to add a certain suffix to every class of a library, when the suffix could be better placed in the namespace itself. That is simply redundant.

In case, however, a certain suffix is necessary to distinguish between related classes inside one library and one namespace, any suffix is fine which is understood well and accepted by your team - whether the suffix is "API", "RestAPI" or "Accessor" (or something else) does not make a huge difference, just let the team pick a convention and stick to it consistently (as @Robert Harvey already wrote in a comment).

Comment: Thanks Doc. I have updated the question with the main reason behind opting the convention. What do you think about that?

Comment: If all (or nearly all) of the APIs are REST, the simple ...API is fine.  Otherwise a longer suffix would help.

Comment: @user949300 - None of the JavaScript browser APIs are REST. None of the APIs of the standard libraries of various languages are REST. None of the operating system APIs are REST. API does not mean "web service".

Comment: @explorer - it's fine; you don't have to be overly expressive/explicit in your naming, as long as it's clear from the context what the name means. The name here is not misleading (it is correct in the abstract sense), so the issue of this name vs that name is not worth spending time on, as changing the name to an ostensibly better one would not achieve anything of substantial value - conceptually, nothing would really change, and the structure/design & maintainability properties of the codebase would remain exactly the same. It would be an uphill battle *and* it would be one not worth fighting

Comment: Thanks Doc, user949300 and Filip. I am now inclined with using some suffixes to differentiate model classes and interface/controllers. I am still not convinced using using a suffix "API"(RestApi or anything else is fine) because it is too generic term. In any case, I am fine with letting it go as it is not worth arguing over as you guys mentioned.

Comment: @explorer: don't forget to utilize namespaces. For example: if your libraries' namespace already contains the term "REST", it should be clear from the context that the suffix API refers to a REST API. This may not work exactly this way in your case (which I don't know, since you did not write anything about your current namespace usings), but I guess you get the idea. Moreover, if you think "API" is too generic, because this could lead to confusion when in the same namespace other types of APIs could exist, it should not be too hard to convince your team about being more specific.